# Compact cygwin terminal

Tags: terminal, cygwin

I'm looking for a way to make the cygwin terminal more compact, or an alternate terminal that is more compact.  Currently, every command I enter has a header line above it with username and pwd, and there is a blank line trailing every command.  For instance:

```
username ~
$ cd tmp

username ~/tmp
$
```

3 lines for every 1 line of command.  I frequently work on a small screen, which makes all this wasted space quite irritating.  Is there a setting somewhere I can alter to prevent all this wasted space?  Or, perhaps another terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default shell prompt set by Cygwin.

To use a smaller prompt in your current terminal:

```
PS1='$ '
```

To make the change permanent, put that command in your `~/.bashrc` file.

You can set the prompt to just about anything you like, as explained by the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) (there are several variables that control different prompts; `$PS1` is the main one).

It's important to remember than in Cygwin (as in Linux and Unix), the terminal program is a separate program from the shell that runs in it.  The prompt is controlled by the shell; bash is the default.  The graphical display is controlled by the terminal emulator, which could be `rxvt`, `mintty`, `xterm`, or even the Windows terminal that normally runs a DOS-like shell.

Comment: Thanks!  Strange that I make edits to `bashrc` frequently, yet it didn't even occur to me that this would be a shell control, rather than terminal.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing there is the prompt, as stored in the environment variable PS1

```
echo $PS1
```

will show you how it's created.  By the way, that prompt is managed by the bash shell, not by the terminal.

```
export PS1=$
```

will give you just a $ prompt

```
export PS1="$ "
```

will leave some room behind the prompt.  There are many more possibilities, [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) is a nice tutorial.

bash reads its settings from a file called `~/.bashrc` aka a file called .bashrc in your home directory.  Note that due to the initial dot in the name ls won't show the file by default, ls -a or ls -la will.

Comment: For a string that contains, or may contain, dollar signs, it's a good idea to use single quotes rather than double quotes to avoid variable expansion. It's not a problem in this case; `"$ "` is equivalent to `'$ '` at least for bash.

Answer (score 0):

I would Recommend we go with modern terminals using Cygwin-X as shown in the below interactive menu

[image]

I love **Xfce Terminal** which allows creating tabs and new windows with font options and color options